# Retrieve variable value from Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

```js
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

    uint public x;
    uint public y;
```

How do I retrieve this value in my nodejs file?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are trying to access those values, `x` and `y` from outside a contract using node / javascript.

You will need a few things:

1. contract ABI (usually a .json file, compiled version of a .sol file)
2. Web3 to be able to interact with the contract ABI

Now, once you have said contract loaded as an instance:

```
    const contract = require("@truffle/contract");
    let abi = contract(<ContractJSON>);
    abi.setProvider(window.web3.currentProvider);
    let contract = await abi.deployed();
    let valX = await contract.x();
```

The above is not quite meant to compile etc, just a reference for you to find your way.

Comment: What about retrieving an array?
People[] public people;
I tried using contract.people() but I get: "Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)"